# Saber cuando cambia la información en un dataGridView

Tags: c#

Tengo información en un dataGridView que no se modifica, cargo la información cuando inicio el formalrio y lo avtualizo con un timer cada 2 segundos.
Necesito saber cada vez que corra el tiempo si hubo algun cambio en los datos del dataGridView

Comment: No se entiende bien tu problema. Vos que queres saber? si cuando hiciste la actualizacion hubo un cambio?

Answer (score 0):

La forma de comparar un conjunto de valores es por medio de su `IEquatable<>`.

[Enumerable.SequenceEqual](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.8)

La idea es poder definir la clase que herede de `IEquatable<>` para asi poder ver si comparar las entidades por `Equals()` o por `GetHashCode()`

Entonces en la clase defines como compara, como en el ejemplo del articulo

```
public class ProductA: IEquatable<ProductA>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(ProductA other)
    {
        if (other is null)
            return false;

        return this.Name == other.Name && this.Code == other.Code;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as ProductA);
    public override int GetHashCode() => (Name, Code).GetHashCode();
}
```

Asi lugo usas

```
bool areEquals = listA.SequenceEqual(listB);
```

Si tienes las lista actual y la nueva que vayas asignar al grid puedes compararlas y ver si hay algun cambio entre estas.